# Web-site with two Composite per page. Due to bad design?

Tags: gwt, mvp, browser-history

I'm creating a web-site using GWT for the first time. The aplication has two Composite class, one of them is a menu and the other one is where I show de info about the specific menu that has been clicked. I'm using MVP, the class History and the interface ChangeValueHandler to switch among different pages.

I have one pair presenter-view for each Composite. The app begins well creating the menu and the section info. When you click in the menu it works fine showing the information and the token browser is changed. The thing is that if you load a page(eg: myapp.com#register) without loading the home page, it doesn't show you the menu. It loads the Composite section info, but not the Composite menu (the Composite menu is load with myapp.com#home).

I think it's because of a bad design of the application, but I don't know how to do that in other way. If the app only had one Composite it wouldn't be a problem, but when there are 2 or more Composite per page I don't know how to manage the whole thing to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell what exactly is wrong, because of the lack of code. So I'm guessing. You should design to act on the PlaceChangeEvent instead of the ValueChangeEvent. That means a menu click should fire the place change and then the application will handle this event. That way you unbind the menu actions from your content pages. And think more of each page as a separate entity. Also take a look at the GWT Activity mechanism and how it helps having a main page that is always the same and on that main page a content area that changes depending on the page actually shown.

Comment: Yesterday, I was changing the code to add Activities and all the stuff that is said in http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html But I've a big problem now: my Activities don't die. Even calling the method onStop() inside the method mayStop() they die. My Activities Mapper works fine, but I don't know why the Activities keep alive, and that's a problem because they are still recieving events from the view.

Comment: You must use the event bus from the start method in the activity, not the one from ClientFactory. If that isn't the problem then I don't understand your problem. For example how can a view generate events? Is it still visible to the user?

Comment: I meant UI events, like ClickEvent. I've had to remove all the handlers in the mayStop() method of the Presenter. With that patch at least Presenters don't do things that I don't want  them to do, althought they're still alive. They enter into the mayStop() method but after that, for a unknown reason, they don't finish.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your menu in each page instead of creating it once in the home page and then keeping it on screen. I assume you create the menu and add it to the DOM via

```
RootPanel.get().add(myMenuWidget);
```

If you are using UIBinder it should be pretty straightforward to include the menu in each page, just a matter of adding the corresponding tag in each .ui.xml file of your pages.